# What is the difference between any other event and an edge triggered event in libevent?

Tags: libevent

what is edge triggered event in libevent?

What is the difference between any other event and an edge triggered event in libevent?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162712/what-is-the-purpose-of-epolls-edge-triggered-option
Since libevent uses epoll internally, I guess this should answer your question.